# How do I undo a rollback in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

I work with a shared SVN. Occasionally, there's a problem with the latest HEAD build, and I need to rollback to a previous version that works while it's being fixed.

I do this by going into the SVN logs, right-click on the revision and select "Revert to this revision", as described here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-howto-rollback.html

When the problem is fixed, how do I go back to the HEAD version (i.e. undo the rollback)? Updating does nothing. The only ways I have are a) deleting all my files and doing a fresh checkout, or b) going to the commit dialog and individually reverting my files (which brings them up to the HEAD version).

This seems pretty awkward and broken, so is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you actually want to do is "Update to revision...", not actually a revert operation. If you know the HEAD (or revision X) is broken, right-click and use "Update to revision..." to update to the latest working revision number. When you're ready to update back to HEAD again just do a normal update. Think that should work anyway!

Edit: Note that I've not actually tried this, but sounds workable to me.

Comment: excellent, that does it. So aside from the SVN docs being wrong, their naming conventions are confusing :D

Comment: It is not that the SVN docs are wrong; it is more that the terminology of source control lends itself to casdcading ambiguity! Where the Subversion docs say "rollback" they are talking about throwing away some number of revisions past a certain point, i.e. a true "undo" operation--and the heading even indicates it is an "undo". When *you* say rollback, you simply want to move back in time temporarily--without throwing away or undoing anything--and you do use `Update` rather than `Revert` to do this, as Wayne has indicated.